# What does "Default Output State" mean for a digital isolator?

Tags: pullup, floating, digital-isolator

I do not understand the term "Default Output State" of the SI8422AB-D-IS
digital isolator. I saw it [on this datasheet](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/si841x-2x-datasheet-1398047.pdf) at page 3:
[image]
Does it mean "the default output voltage if the input pin is floating"? (so this means that the input pin is pulled up internally?)

Just for the record, I want to use a digital isolator for a USB communication protocol between a computer and a MCU, at around 9600 Baud, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in table 4.1, the default state gets output when the input side is unpowered.

"Floating" means that the voltage has a random value, and moves around randomly. If an input pin has a pull-up or pull-down resistor, then its voltage would not be able to float. This device does not have a pull-up resistor; an open input can float, and it reads either low or high, depending on what the voltage happens to be.